# Objects are not valid as a react child" Error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to get rid of the error in my case:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child 
  (found: object with keys {_id, title, text, tags, viewsCount, user, createdAt, updatedAt, __v}). 
  If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Code

```
export const Post = ({
  id,
  title,
  createdAt,
  imageUrl,
  user,
  viewsCount,
  commentsCount,
  tags,
  children,
  isFullPost,
  isLoading,
  isEditable
}) => {
  if (isLoading) {
    return <PostSkeleton />;
```

From another file:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`/posts/${id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data);
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.warn(err);
        alert("Error in receiving the post");
      });
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Post isLoading={isLoading} isFullPost />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Post
        id={data._id}
        title={data.title}
        imageUrl={data.imageUrl}
        user={data.user}
        createdAt={data.createdAt}
        viewsCount={data.viewsCount}
        commentsCount={0}
        tags={data.tags}
        isFullPost
      >
        <p>{data.text}</p>
      </Post>
    </>
  }
 );
};
```

Comment: AFAICT there's not enough information here to help.

Comment: You didn't paste the full code for `Post`, please [fix that](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.